# GWT g:Anchor doesn't show up as a link

Tags: java, gwt, anchor, uibinder

I've just started learning UiBinder approach and having a stupid problem with `g:Anchor`. Whenever I construct `Anchor` directly from Java code, it's displayed as a "normal link", so it's blue, underlined and when I move mouse pointer to it, it gets switched from I-Beam to normal arrow.

When I use UiBinder and define my UI like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:Anchor ui:field="anchor" />
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The result I get is a blue text, but it's neither underlined nor mouse pointer becomes normal arrow when I move it to this link. The only solution I've found is

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:Anchor ui:field="anchor" href="javascript:;" />
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Is there a "correct" approach to achieve the same behavior without copypasting that `href` attribute everywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4502

But the thing is that you shouldn't use an Anchor if you don't have an `href` to set on it. If you want something that looks and feels like an anchor but doesn't link to some URL, then use a Label or HTML with the appropriate styling and a `ClickHandler`; don't abuse anchors for things that aren't links.